# How to create Listener in objective C like HttpListners

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I want to create an mac app which listens to some url(example SOME_HOST_NAME:0001/) that is whenever the request is made to that url i have to perform some task and also send back the response. How can I accomplish the task in objective C?
Please tell if any more information is required.

Comment: Are you going to be the server that listens on this port, or do you want to intercept requests to some other server on the system, or do you want to intercept requests from clients on the system to a server somewhere else?

Comment: yes, I want to intercept requests from clients on the system to a server somewhere else.